# Where can i revoke Freeze and Mint Authority safe? Orion tools bugged

Tags: spl-token, mint, freeze-token-account

Well i just created a token with **orion tools**, but when i select it and click on **revoke freeze or revoke mint, the transaction does not complete**, it does not charge me the **0.1** sol and i cant revoke it.

Does anyone knows another website so i can do it? I´ve heard that keyglowmax is a **scam**, wonder if **https://tools.smithii.io/revoke-freeze/solana is legit or not**.

If not, **is https://www.dexlab.space/ safe?**

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen as well. I've read that it may take multiple attempts due to congestion. I imagine their sight is getting a lot of use now. Looking forward to hearing feedback from others.